# Laravel join 3 table and select raw sum

Tags: laravel, join, sum

I have a 3 tables in Laravel project

First table "offers"

| id | client | numer_offer | id_user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 211/2022 | 11 |
| 2. | 145 | 212/2022 | 23 |

Second table "clients"

| id | name | adres |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Mark | 211/2022 |
| 145 | Ben | 212/2022. |

A the last table "offer_items"

| id | id_offer | product | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | bags | 14.56 |
| 2 | 2 | bags2 | 16.50 |

And have a query:

```
  $id_user = '11';
  $offers = Offer::join('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'offers.client')
  ->join('offer_items','.offer_items.id_offer', '=', 'offers.id')
  ->selectRaw(' sum(offer_items.amount) as suma, clients.name, offers.*')
  ->where('offers.id_user', $id_user)
  ->groupBy('offer_items.id_offer')
  ->Orderby('offers.id_offer')
  ->get();
```

the query works fine if I have a record in "offer_items", but if I have no record in the table, nothing shows, and I would like everything to be displayed and amount = 0.

any idea because yesterday I was up all day :(

Comment: are you sure that mentioned data correct ? 
the clients ids that in offers [123,145] not exists in `clients` table

Comment: i correct example table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `leftJoin` instead of `join` at joining with `offer_items`, to retrieve data whether has records on `offer_items` or not , also i added `IFNULL` to treat null as 0

```
$id_user = '11';
 $offers = Offer::join('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'offers.client')
      ->leftJoin('offer_items','offer_items.id_offer', '=', 'offers.id')
      ->selectRaw(' sum(IFNULL(offer_items.amount,0)) as suma, clients.name, offers.*')
      ->where('offers.id_user', $id_user)
      ->groupBy('offers.id')
      ->Orderby('offers.id')
      ->get();
```

more details about [different type of join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) , [Mysql IFNULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp)

Comment: not working, if offer_items don't have any record

Comment: @timber.km updated kindly check